# How to avoid multiple deleter lambdas?

Tags: c++, lambda

How to avoid multiple deleter lambdas with the following:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

auto del = [](A *p) { delete static_cast<A*>(p); }
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A, void (*)(A*)>> vec;

vec.emplace_back(new B, del); //[1]
/* OR */
vec.emplace_back(new B, [](A *p) { delete static_cast<B*>(p); }); //[2]
```

So a class `B` that inherites `A` is put into a `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr<A>` with custom deleter to properly invoke `B`'s destructor. The deleter is a lambda and as far as I know doing this:

```
auto l1 = []{};
auto l2 = []{};
```

will yield two separate types even though the lambdas are the same since the lambdas are anonymous `struct`s internally. Is there a way for the vector's elements (`unique_ptr`s) above to use only **one** lambda deleter for all of them? Perhaps by pre-declaring it and passing it to `emplace_back` like in [1]? Or is it pretty much the same as giving "new" lambda for every such call as in [2]?

Comment: What happened to virtual destructors? Are they OK?

Comment: @n.m. I have a very simple structs that share common ancestor. Giving them v-table is not ok in my opinion in this case since I can actually type the above out and save some runtime performance, v-table lookups etc. Generally they are ok of course as is use of `std::shared_ptr` that captures the deleter automatically... with another overhead of reference counting.

Comment: You may still use regular function (or functor in case of capture).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that compiler will optimize code to have only one deleter function BTW.

Comment: Looks like abuse of inheritance to me, but anyway. So instead of adding a pointer to each object, you are adding a pointer to each unique_ptr? Doesn't seem a very good trade-off to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to avoid the creation of a lot of lambdas in [2] (which would probably get optimized away anyway), [1] is a good way, although the lambda instance will get copied every time you add a new object (probably also optimized away, but I'm not sure).

But, if you don't want to deal with the hassle of passing the deleter every time you add a `std::unique_ptr`, make a functor:

```
struct deleter {
    void operator()(A *p) const noexcept { delete static_cast<B*(p); }
};
```

Because `deleter` is DefaultConstructible, the constructor of `std::unique_ptr` can create a deleter object itself, without you having to pass one. This is not possible with lambdas, as they are not DefaultConstructible.

Comment: All of your `unique_ptr`s now have the same deleter that knows about `B`. This kind of defeats the purpose of having a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A,...>>`. You cannot add a pointer-to-genuine-A to it any more. Could just as well have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>>`.

Comment: @n.m. Not really. Base class pointers pointing to derived class memory is still useful, and now they have the same semantic (no deleter had to be passed) as pointers to base and derived. If that makes sense.

Comment: You have three kinds of pointers now: pointer-to-base, pointer-to-derived and pointer-to-base-subobject-of-derived, any one incompatible with any other. If that's what you want...

Answer (score 1):

Deleters are copied into every `unique_ptr` by the constructor. It doesn't matter what you do with the lambda, every `unique_ptr` object will have a copy of it.

On a side note, I recommend against giving the type of the deleter as a function pointer. Instead use the `decltype` of lambda to avoid indirection call. Will save you some performance. Also, non-capturing lambda will likely take 0 bytes of storage for `unique_ptr`, while function pointer will take `sizeof(void*)` for every `unique_ptr` you have.

Comment: Good point about the use of `decltype`. However I disagree about the lambda. You are right it will be copied to every element but what **type** that will be? I believe that in my [2] it will be different type for every element (though the signature will be the same). Bu I think using `decltype` instead of function pointer should ensure it will be only one type though. Is that correct?

Comment: @Resurrection No, it will only have the type of the lambda you called `decltype` on. If you try to assign a different lambda, it will fail because the types are different.

Comment: @Rakete1111 That is what I said. :-) And quick check reveals that I was right, using `decltype` does not allow doing [2] in OP. Which answers my original question as well. [2] syntax actually creates a different lambda per element!

Comment: Deleter itself is not a lambda, it is whatever template argument you use. If your type is function pointer, a lambda will be converted to function pointer, as non-capturing lambdas will. Still every object will have the same function pointer. If you are worried about the size of the unique_ptr, non-capturing lambda is likely to require storage of 0 bytes, while function pointer will take sizeof(void*) - say, 8 bytes.

Comment: @SergeyA That is incorrect I believe. Deleter template argument can be whatever but in my case I used function pointer. The lambda does not get "converted" to anything, it will simply be invoked through that pointer. And lambda is a struct with operator(). If I used [1] syntax then you would be right, all elements would have the same lambda and pointer to it. However if I used [2] every element would have its own lambda and its own pointer to it.

Comment: @Resurrection, nope. In your example lambda is converted to function pointer, non-capturing lambdas can do that. Try capturing lambda and behold compilation error.

Comment: @SergeyA Ah alright then, one learns something new every day. Does that mean that in this case the [1] and [2] are identical?

Comment: @Resurrection, identical in which way?

Comment: @SergeyA The number of types created.

Comment: Every lambda has unique type. Your example (2) creates a unique type of lambda for every insertion, but this is not relevant, since the type is converted to function pointer. Compiler will optimize all those pointers to point to the same function, though.